# Complete Login code in Xamarin cross platform using Sqllite database

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms and i have to implement a login model. I have inserted values in the Sqlite database and now i have match the username and password from the database that i am unable to do. PLEASE HELP ME WITH THE CODE.

Comment: "Avoid Copy paste",   try at-least through the link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases) , and then If you get any problem/error while coding then post here.

Answer (score 0):

If you storing credentials or other personal data in an SQLite DB, don't forget to encrypt it.

On iOS I recommend you to use the keychain.

If you want to store personal data in a secure way without writing platform for each platform, I have created a plugin for that, https://github.com/TinyStuff/TinyAccountManager

Comment: Encrypting passwords is a security risk - only store the salted hash from passwords